# CentOS IPC msg queue filling up with messages from PHP application

Tags: php, linux, ipc, centos6, sysv

I have a long-running PHP application that spawns multiple child processes to run tasks on a CentOS VM, and it uses the SysV IPC message queue (via msg_get_queue(), etc) for sending events to the parent process.

The problem is that even though the children nicely execute msg_remove_queue() prior to exiting, message resources seem to stick around at the system level. Eventually this fills up the message queue until it reaches kernel.msgni.

The funny thing is that when I run

```
ipcs
```

as the user this script runs under, I see the message queues appearing and disappearing as expected. However, when I run the same command as root, the list of queues slowly and continuously grows, with many of these in the list:

```
0x00000000 1031634944 <user>  0          0            0
```

I'm not an expert with the SysV message queue, so I'm a little unsure of the best solution here, or whether there is a good solution. For the time being, I have set kernel.msgni to 100,000(!). I'm unsure if this is a good idea on a 1GB box.

Note that the permissions are 0 and bytes used is also 0. So theoretically these queues are not taking up any space, although at some point I would expect that just having the system iterate over these is a load on the system.

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Will these resources ever expire, time out or otherwise disappear?
3. Is there some solution I'm not seeing?